# Can't call git.cmd to write output to file?

Tags: git, batch-file, cmd

I need to call git log from a batch file and append the data to a file.  I have researched and tried calling git.exe, git.cmd and lastly the batch line below which gave me an error. Any suggestions?

Command in batch file:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.cmd" log --pretty="format:<author>%an</author>%n<date>%ai</date>%n<msg>don't care</msg>%n" --name-only >> "output.txt"
```

The response:

```
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.cmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Do you have git installed?

Comment: Yes, I have git installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try and simply call `git`: if it is in your `%PATH%`, a `.bat` script will be able to execute it (no `call` needed)

```
git log --pretty="format:<author>%an</author>%n<date>%ai</date>%n<msg>don't care</msg>%n" --name-only >> "output.txt"
```

As shown here, you might have to escape some character, or double the '`%`', in order to be sure and avoid `%...` to be interpreted by the CMD shell session.